# Image Filtering/Categorization/Recognition

Tags: python, image, text, camera, raspberry-pi

So, im basically looking for a fast method of filtering images of a single black letter from a white Background on a Raspberry Pi.

The images would be scaled slightly different and may be taken from a different angle, but the letter would almost certainly be like a quarter of the picture.

The image has to be taken and instantly looked at and categorized. Lets say we have the letters A, B and C. The task would be to take the photo (by an extra camera module directly on the Raspberry PI) and then return the output(the letter, at best saved in an extra variable) to another program. The whole process should be as fast as possible and it should be executed on command for a rate of maybe once every 2-10 seconds (based on situation)

I had the idead of using PyTesseract but I saw lots of evidence, that tesseract takes a lot of time (or is it just for larger images/text?)

Comment: Do you know in advance the full range of letters that might be photographed? Are there digits too? Is the font fixed? Is it always the same piece of card with the same letters in the same font, or could it be a different font every time?

Comment: It would be H, S and U to be exact

Comment: The font would be any sans serif typeface like "Arial" and it would be the uppercase letter only like moved around in the picture (more on the left or like 3cm higher) something like this. But no serious changes for the letters.

Comment: Do you have some sample images?

Comment: H for example (Image attached). The thiccness of the lines is shorter in reality and the resolution of the image will be worse (just a fast example image). https://iserv-gis.de/iserv/fs/file/mail/INBOX/2120/2

Comment: Sry, image isnt viewable for you. Here is it again:https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/426142331570487296/492028340245364747/IMG_20180919_144320.jpg